# How to present a modal view, not overlapped by the keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover). Everything works well until I want to present the popover when there is a keyboard. The sequence of events are:

- click on a text field
- keyboard shows up as usual
- click a button to trigger popover

  [image]

Here is the FPPopover code to add its view:

```
NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
if(windows.count > 0)
{
      _parentView=nil;
    _window = [windows objectAtIndex:0];
    //keep the first subview
    if(_window.subviews.count > 0)
    {
        _parentView = [_window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        [_parentView addSubview:self.view];
        [_viewController viewDidAppear:YES];
    }

}
```

How can I make the popover view *not* overlapped by the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to have the keyboard visible at all times? If not, have your view dismiss the keyboard when the modal view is presented.

You can do this by calling sending resignFirstResponder to a view object (such as a textView).

Once the modal view is closed, send becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: For this particular app, yes, I want the keyboard visible when FPPopover is being shown.